# How to Lint check Laravel's Blade Templates?

Tags: php, laravel, automated-tests, laravel-blade, lint

On my new Laravel project, I came across some error on Laravel's Blade template file. I tried to search Linter tool for Blade but couldn't find none.

There are various great plugins available for PHP lint testing.

I recently came across [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/)

Can anyone help me with Linting of Blade.

Thank you for going through my question.

Comment: May this link will help you. https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade

Comment: Hi. It is just a highlighter. It doesn't alert on errors. Thanks, though.